# How to republish tf as topic

Tags: ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to provide yaw-correction for my IMU algorithm running on an embedded platform using /map -> /base_link `tf` obtained via `gmapping`. For that I need yaw-angle as ROS topic, not a tf. I'd like to write a simple node to listen to `tf`'s and republish the data as soon as it comes. I've read in some post the best way to do it would be subscribing to `/tf`-topic.

I'm assuming this is actually the best solution, so my main question is how to programatically subscribe to `/tf' and only react to certain tf being published. Do you know a good existing example of such behaviour? I'm also open to other suggestions.

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12399/how-to-republish-tf-as-topic/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why you want to do it with a topic. `tf` provides a very simple method to find transforms, the [TransformListener](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29). This gives you the ability to always look up the most recent transform between two frames, which is what I believe you are trying to do.

If, for some reason, you HAVE to subscribe to /tf, you can write a node that has a subscriber to the `/tf` topic, checks the "header.frame_id" and "child_frame_id" fields and determines whether or not to republish based on that information.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-19**:
In that case, give option B a shot.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-19**:
Thanks, I'll try it. It has to be a topic, as I don't have means on my embedded platform to listen to tf's, just topics. Besides I have a very limited bandwidth so I have to limit data transfer to necessary minimum.